# Param changes when passed to query?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

ive recently switched to c# from vb.net and keep bumping into the odd thing.

This has me scratching my head, but is probably stupidly simple, could someone point out what im missing?

I have an IEnumerable object with entities in it, 3 entities at the moment.

```
AAA, orange, blue, red    
BBB, green, yellow, pink    
CCC, orange, pink, red
```

using the code below i seem to get the last elements code (the three letters), and only that, three times. so output will be:

```
Running Company code: CCC    
Running Company code: CCC    
Running Company code: CCC
```

if i step through, it is passing each one, but i think somehow it its changing it in the foreach loop before its put to console. If i put the console.writeline in the loop, then I will get the expected result.

```
Running Company code: AAA    
Running Company code: BBB    
Running Company code: CCC
```

Ive not tested it, but im sure this would work fine in VB.Net, can someone explain what im missing, its probably right infront of my face no doubt.

```
    public void lookForWork()
    {     

       var custs = _IRepository.GetCustomers();
       var conf = _IRepository.GetConfig(); 

       foreach (var custRow in custs)
       { 

       worker = new BackgroundWorker();
       worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
       worker.DoWork += (obj, e) => checkWork(conf.Where(x => x.Code == custRow.Code).SingleOrDefault());
       worker.RunWorkerAsync();

       }

    }

    private void checkWork(CustomerConfigEntity custInfo)
    { 
        console.WriteLine(String.Format("Running Company code: {0}", custInfo.Code));
    }
```

Comment: Don't you get a warning about 'do not use the iteration variable in a lambda...' or something along those lines?

Comment: Nope, it runs fine, just unexpected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have run into the "foreach loop variable in a closure" bug.

Either use C# 5.0, or write:

```
public void lookForWork()
{     
   var custs = _IRepository.GetCustomers();
   var conf = _IRepository.GetConfig(); 

   foreach (var custRow in custs)
   { 
       var localCustRow = custRow;
       worker = new BackgroundWorker();
       worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
       worker.DoWork += (obj, e) => 
           checkWork(conf.Where(x => x.Code == localCustRow.Code).SingleOrDefault());
       worker.RunWorkerAsync();
   }
}
```

For more information, see the excelent articles by Eric Lippert on the subject:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx

Comment: That works brilliantly, and the best bugs are always Microsoft bugs that become our bugs!

Thank you Kris, tried to upvote but cant on this account yet.